# Dialogflow - Get two similar type values in one intent

Tags: dialogflow-es

I need to get two addresses in an intent in Dialogflow. When the user enters the first address, there is no problem, but when user enters the second address, it updates the first address and does not fill in the second address. Since the address structures are in certain patterns, the training phrases are similar to each other and therefore one of the addresses currently remains blank.

my structure is:

```
{FirstAddress - @sys.address - $FirstAddress} 
{SecondAddress - @sys.address - $SecondAddress}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try and consider the below approach to fit in your use case.

You can [manually annotate](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/intents-training-phrases#annotation) the **first address input** from your training phrase into your `FirstAddress` parameter and then the **second address input** to `SecondAddress` parameter just like this:

[image]

**Output would be:**

[image]